# How to use a stream cipher to sign a message?

Tags: signature, protocol-design, symmetric, stream-cipher

Are there known constructions which allow to sign a message M
(let's say it will be sent as clear text) using a stream cipher C
and a symmetric secret key K?
So, we have M, C, K and we want to send M|S
where S = SIGN(C,K,M) and | is the concatenation operator.

Comment: You may be looking for [mesage authentication codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

Comment: Universal hash + symmetric cipher is a common MAC construction. E.g. Poly1305 is used that way in the TLS cipher suite.

Comment: I *think* you *could* build a block cipher from the stream cipher and use said block cipher to implement a standard MAC (e.g. CMAC).

Comment: A stream cipher generates a key stream. The key stream is then XOR'ed with the plain text. The problem is that a stream cipher doesn't collect any state when that's happening. So you *at least* need some kind of compression function in addition to the stream cipher.

Comment: I was thinking about using the stream cipher to encrypt only the output of an error detection code that was applied to M or something along those lines.

Comment: @UnixJunkie what you're describing is exactly how Poly1305 works. But I'm curious, what's the reason you want to use a cipher for this instead of an HMAC?

Answer (score 3):

Many caveats: I'm not qualified to write this answer, but hopefully other folks can correct my mistakes. Outside of NaCl's [crypto_box](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html) and [crypto_secretbox](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/secretbox.html) constructions, there are a lot of ways to misuse a polynomial MAC. That might be why Thomas Ptacek [specifically recommends **against** them](https://gist.github.com/tqbf/be58d2d39690c3b366ad). The standard way to sign a message using a symmetric key is HMAC, and this question seems like kind of an "assuming I'm forced to used a stream cipher instead of a hash for some reason" thought experiment.

That said.

Poly1305 is the authenticator in NaCl, and it's built with a stream cipher. First it feeds your message into a big polynomial, to give a checksum. The coefficients of the polynomial are derived from the bytes of your message, and the value of `x` in the polynomial comes from half of your secret key. Then it encrypts that checksum, using the other half of your secret key along with a nonce. The cipher for encrypting the checksum can be anything; it was AES in the [original paper](https://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf) and it's XSalsa20 in the [NaCl implementation](https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf). You need the cipher because the checksum by itself can leak the `x` that generated it.

One important difference between a polynomial MAC and a hash, is that it's easy to find collisions in the polynomial. If you know `x` you can find its multiplicative inverse, and then you can mix that into a message to control the exact checksum you end up with. A polynomial MAC *doesn't uniquely determine its input* like a good cryptographic hash does.

Another important difference is that the polynomial MAC relies on a unique nonce (for the cipher) to keep its key secret, which means *nonce reuse is extra specially terrible*.